# JSON format in asp.net web api

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api

In ASP.NET Web API, I return json as

```
[{"EmpID":"20160636","FullName":"Md Delower Hossain"}]
```

But I want that as the following:

```
{"EmpID":"20160636","FullName":"Md Delower Hossain"}
```

The parenthesis `[]` should be omitted for my programming purpose. What can I do?

Comment: You should show your code that produces this output.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of returning a collection from your Web API endpoint, you could return a single element:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("api/employees")]
public IHttpActionResult Index()
{
    IEnumerable<Employee> employees = ...

    Employee employee = employees.FirstOrDefault();
    return this.Ok(employee);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you do not provide any code in your question I assume that you return any kind of **collection object** which gets serialized to JSON in array form.

If you want to return just **a single object** basically exactly what you need to do in order to achieve that is to return a single object. If your type is called Employee, just return a single instance of Employee from the controller method.

Answer (score -2):

You have to trim the parenthesis.

```
stringcurrentJson ="[{"EmpID":"20160636","FullName":"Md Delower Hossain"}]";
var ExpectedJson= JObject.Parse(currentJson .Trim(new char[] { '[', ']' }));
```

then u can use the ExpectedJson wherever u want